# Declare javascript static array in function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table containing 21 `checkboxes` (rows of 7 days times three columns of time of day). I want an **onClick function** to toggle individual columns of three times of date on or off. I have written this `JavaScript` function:

```
function toggleCol(colnum)
{
    if (typeof toggleCol.state == 'undefined') toggleCol.state = false;
    toggleCol.state = !toggleCol.state;
    document.getElementById("req" + colnum).checked = toggleCol.state;
    document.getElementById("req" + (colnum + 7)).checked = toggleCol.state;
    document.getElementById("req" + (colnum + 14)).checked = toggleCol.state;
}
```

This works but the obvious problem is that I need not one but seven `toggleCol.state` variables, one for each column, presumably as an array.

How do I declare and use a static array of seven members within the function? I've tried every way I can think of but I've run out of ideas!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your code ?

Comment: If I knew how, I would certainly do so. I'm a beginner at this!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ there you can paste your html and js for everyone to see :)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/g0L34x0z/ . The onClicks don't work, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select and hide all cells of one column you can try: $('td:nth-child(number_of_column)').hide();

Comment: OK. But I don't want to hide the cells, but to toggle the state of the checkbox in the cell.

Comment: So $('td:nth-child(number_of_column)').toogle();